# Use generated Kerberos tickets in Chromium browser

Tags: chromium, authentication

Has anyone had luck using Kerberos tickets generated with kinit in Chromium for authenticating to websites?

The company I work for supports Kerberos authentication to internal websites, and I'm able to configure Firefox to use generated Kerberos tickets by configuring network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris and network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris but I don't if/how I can do this in Chromium...

Comment: Are you still looking for help or have you solved this problem? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Authentication options of Chromium are described at http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication

For Kerberos, you need the command line option `--auth-server-whitelist=.example.com`

In Ubuntu, you can add this command line option to the file `/etc/chromium-browser/default`

Comment: the same flag works for `google-chrome` too.

Comment: I think the command line option is gone and you need to switch to policies. https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start

Answer (score 2):

Create a chrome policy file like below. Please note that Chrome `*Whitelist` settings have recently changed to `*Allowlist`.

```bash
cat << HEREDOC | sudo tee /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/kerberos.json > /dev/null
{
    "AuthServerAllowlist": "*.yourdomain.com",
    "AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist": "*.yourdomain.com"
}
HEREDOC
```

(The fancy `sudo tee` stuff is just to acquire write permission.)

Comment: For my organization, I also had to add this line after the AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist line: `"AuthSchemes": "digest,ntlm,negotiate"`